# Unwanted trim of whitespace in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Hi I am having a strange issue.

```
childelement = DOMObject.createElement("MY_KEY")
childelement.text = myObject.myKey
childelement = topelement.appendChild(childelement)
```

In the above code the value of `myObject.myKey is "    24"`. 
but when I do `childelement.text = myObject.myKey` the value of `childelement.text` becomes "24".
The white space is automatically removed. I don't won't that to happen. The value must be 
"    24".

Why is this happening ? how to fix?

Comment: Why did you tag this with C#?

Comment: Guess C# developers must have worked with vb also. C# is kind of advanced so

Comment: @GeoPaul: If C# developers want to see questions about VB, they would look for VB-tagged questions. The question actually has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: Thanks for removing the C# tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a *workaround* by defining something like

```
write_stuff = "." + your_text + "."
```

and when you read it, then you use

```
read_stuff = read.stuff.Replace(".", "")
```

However, it is not very clear why whitespaces are required, and it may be a good idea to overthink that, too

**Update**

if there is no char to use, then simply cut off that added part afterwards:

```
bla = Mid(bla, 2, bla.Length - 2)
```

this cuts away first and last char

Comment: hmm.. the option you provided might work. But I would prefer to do it as my last option. because my text might contain lots of special chars. so I must be carefull

Comment: updated another workaround. Still not a perfect solution, but if no other exist, then at least it is one easy to apply